# Web browser bookmarklet that launches an EXE on my C: drive

Tags: javascript, html, windows, bookmarklet

I wish to write a JavaScript program that executes a Windows EXE from my local C: drive. I understand the security implications, and would like to do this anyway.

I wrote a small JavaScript that's "supposed" to launch an executable.  However, it does absolutely nothing.

**Full path to exe:**

```
C:\Program Files\shareURL\shareURL.exe
```

Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
    MyObject = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" )  
    function RunExe()   
    {  
    MyObject.Run("file:///C:/Program%20Files/ShareURL%203/shareURL.exe") ;  
}  
</script> 
RunExe()
```

I would like to make the code in a format that allows me to convert it to a web browser bookmarket using **online JavaScript-->bookmarklet creators** such as: [Bookmarklet Creator with Script Includer](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/)

Eventually, I plan on making a browser extension that adds a button to the toolbar. However, I would like to have something close to it in the meantime.

Comment: Which browser? ActiveXObject is only a thing in Internet Explorer, according to https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject

Comment: Chromium based browsers.  I don't think Internet Explorer is still available

Comment: I don't think Chromium based browsers will let you do something that dangerous in a bookmarklet. You'd have to look into alternative solutions, like using a browser extension, or running a local web server which listens to certain fetch requests.

Comment: @Stefnotch FYI, someone already made a great Chromium/Firefox extension that uses `node.js` to execute external exe's and scripts.  It works great.   https://webextension.org/listing/external-application-button.html.

Comment: Awesome, would you mind adding that as a complete answer then? Comments are only meant to be temporary, and a proper answer might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the below solution isn't precisely what I was looking for, it's actually closer to my ultimate goal.. creating a Chromium-based browser extension that executes a Windows EXE of my choice.

I ended up using the below Chromium/Firefox browser extension leverages `node.js` to execute an external EXE of my choice by just clicking on the Extension icon on my web browser's address bar:

It's very simple to install and add my EXE for it to execute.

https://webextension.org/listing/external-application-button.html